# Lista de compras dentro de função

Tags: php, lista

Estou a tentar resolver um exercício que estou a fazer de PHP (sou iniciante) mas não estou a conseguir fazer com que o código funcione, a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: produtos in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste3.php on
>   line 39"

[Código](http://codepaste.net/8xcz2f):

```
$br = "</br>";

function lista($artigos) {

    $produtos = array(
        'Leite' => array('preco' => 0.8, ),
        'Iogurte' => array(
            'preco' => 0.25,
        ),
        'Queijo' => array(
            'preco' => 2.2,
        ),
        'Peixe' => array(
            'preco' => 3.1,
        ),
        'Carne' => array(
            'preco' => 3.5,
        ),
        'Bolachas' => array(
            'preco' => 0.6,
        ),
    );

}
if (isset($_GET['produto'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['quantidade'])) {
        echo 'Preço por unidade: '.$produtos[$_GET['produto']]['preco'].
        '<br>';
        echo 'Preço total: '.$produtos[$_GET['produto']]['preco'] * $_GET['quantidade'];
    } else {
        echo 'nao existe essa quantidade';
    }
} else {
    echo ' nao existe esse produto!';
}
```

Exercício : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Ola @stderr, eu quero que quando faça directamente no browser por exemplo: http://localhost/teste3.php?produto=Queijo&quantidade=30 apareça o preço do produto e neste caso a soma do mesmo (x30) mas quando corro dá erro "Notice: Undefined variable: produtos in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste3.php on line 39"

Comment: Comece por aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Já fiz o tour..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para a proxima é melhor colocar a parte relevante codigo aqui, para ajudar a quem o quer ajudar, nem toda a gente tem tempo/quer ir a links externos para ver código.

Pode fazer assim, sugiro estas melhorias:

```
<?php
function procurar($produto) {
    $produtos = array(
        'Leite' => array('preco' => 0.8,
        ),
        'Iogurte' => array(
            'preco' => 0.25,
        ),
        'Queijo' => array(
            'preco' => 2.2,
        ),
        'Peixe' => array(
            'preco' => 3.1,
        ),
        'Carne' => array(
            'preco' => 3.5,
        ),
        'Bolachas' => array(
            'preco' => 0.6,
        ),
    );
    $produto = ucwords(strtolower($produto));
    if(array_key_exists($produto, $produtos)) {
        return $produtos[$produto];
    }
    return false;
}
if(isset($_GET['produto'])) {
    $prod = procurar($_GET['produto']);
    if($prod) {
        if(isset($_GET['quantidade'])) {
            echo 'Preço por unidade: ' .$prod['preco']. '<br>';
            echo 'Preço total: ' .$prod['preco']*$_GET['quantidade'];
        }
        else {
            echo 'nao existe essa quantidade';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo ' nao existe esse produto!';
    }
}
else {
   echo 'Produto invalido';
}
```

A função deve retornar algo, neste caso retorna os dados do produto que quer, fiz também de maneira a que a busca por chave no array seja [case insencitive](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive)

Comment: É isso mesmo Miguel! Penso que seja a melhor maneira e obrigado pela dica do case insenctive ! Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @MarioCaeiro. Editei, pois os echos de baixo estavam trocados

Comment: Ainda estou muito verdinho, não tinha reparado! Obrigado

Comment: @Miguel Já que as chaves do *array* começam com letra maiúscula, o [`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucwords.php) também pode servir, por exemplo: `$produto = ucwords(strtolower($produto))`. :)

Comment: Sim claro, é verdade @stderr , escusava de mudar as chaves do próprio array, tens razão, vou editar

Answer (score 2):

Use o `isset` antes para verificar se a variável foi definida.

```
function verificarProduto($produto, $quantidade) {
    $produtos = array('Leite' => array('preco' => 0.8, ),
                      'Iogurte' => array('preco' => 0.25, ),
                      'Queijo' => array('preco' => 2.2, ),
                      'Peixe' => array('preco' => 3.1, ),
                      'Carne' => array('preco' => 3.5, ),
                      'Bolachas' => array('preco' => 0.6, ),
                );

     if ($produto) {
         // Verifica se o produto existe na lista de produtos
         if (isset($produtos[$produto])) {
             // Pega o preço do produto
             $preco = $produtos[$produto]['preco'];
             echo "{$produto} existe na lista! Preço por unidade: {$preco} <br>";

             // Se a quantidade for especificada
             if ($quantidade) {
                 $total = $quantidade * $preco;
                 echo "Total: {$total} <br>";
             }
         }
         else {
             echo "{$produto} não existe. <br>";
         }
     }
}

// Verifica se foi atribuído os valores, em caso negativo, atribui-se "false" 
$produto = isset($_GET['produto']) ? $_GET['produto']: false;
$quantidade = isset($_GET['quantidade']) ? $_GET['quantidade']: false;

verificarProduto($produto, $quantidade);
```

Comment: seu código é limpo e explicito, obrigado pela ajuda serve na perfeição também para o que precisava de fazer! Obrigado pelo tempo despendido !